# attempt to add event listener to onclick event using document.queryselector not working

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to add a really simple event listener for an onclick event to test something else that is not working. Since I'm new to programming, I decided to create a random div with some text inside in order to practice recording onclick events. Here is an example of my html doc (part of a much larger document that is formatted correctly):

```
 <main>
                <div class = "test"> Hello </div>
```

and my js looks like this:

```
var testing = document.querySelector(".test");

testing.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Test");
});
```

However, this is not working. I thought, maybe I need to make the div box bigger for ease of clicking (really just trying anything) and so this is what I did in my stylesheet:

```
.test{
    height: 100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

I really am not sure what's going on, since I've tried to make simple event listeners before and did not have any issues...

Comment: 1) Is your script included on the page?  2) Are there console errors? 3) Is your script on the page *after* your html?

Comment: If you have multiple DIVs with that class, this only adds the listener to the first one.

Comment: If you want to do all of them, use `querySelectorAll()` and loop over the results.

Comment: @Taplar 1) script is included on the page, 2) no console errors, 3) script is located right before the closing body tag

Comment: @Barmar there are not multiple divs with this class. which is why I created a class exclusively labeled 'test".

Comment: whatever code you have provided seems to be working fine.

Comment: Then this logic in isolation should work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rk2u5vfj/  Works fine.

Comment: If you examine the element in DevTools, does the Event Listeners panel say there's a click listener attached to it?

Comment: @Barmar not that I can see, no.

Comment: Are you sure the `addEventListener()` code is being executed? Put `console.log("Added listener")` after it.

Comment: Do you have any later code that assigns to the `innerHTML` of the `<main>` element? That will destroy the element that you added the listener to.

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. There can be so many reasons, we can't really try to think of all of them.

Comment: And DevTools has plenty of features you can use to debug this. You can set breakpoints in the code, break on modifications to the DOM, etc.

Comment: @Barmar could you please explain in another way what you mean by "assigns to the `innerHTML` of the `<main>` element"?

Comment: `document.elementsByTagName("main")[0].innerHTML = something;` for example.